# Create new file - exception options?

Tags: java, exception

My assignment is to write a program that copies an existing file into a new file. The program prompts the user for the name of the existing file and then asks for the name of the new file (to create a copy of existing).

If the file already exists, 3 options should be presented:
1. Exit the program
2. Overwrite the existing file
3. Enter a new name for the file

In my project folder, I have two files old.txt and new.txt. When I enter them, it does not state the file already exists, it simply just overwrites the existing new.txt. Here is my code:

```
   existingFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the "
        + "existing file: ");

    try
    {
        file = new File(existingFile);
        inputFile1 = new Scanner(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, existingFile +
                " does not exist. Exiting program.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    newFile = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the "
            + "new file: ");
    try
    {
        file2 = new File(newFile);
        createFile = file2.createNewFile();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Copying " + existingFile +
                " into " + newFile);
    }
    catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, newFile + " already exists.");
        System.out.println("Choose from the following choices:");
        System.out.println("1. Exit the program");
        System.out.println("2. Overwrite the existing file");
        System.out.println("3. Enter a new name for the file");
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something");
    }
```

Can you tell me why I am not getting an exception? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29), `File#createNewFile` does not throw an exception but just returns false.

If you are on a recent Java version, you should use [`Files#createFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) instead (which will throw the exception). The new `Files`/`Path` API is a cleaned-up version for doing file I/O (the legacy one has to be kept for compatibility).

Comment: Same with `new File()`. It doesn't throw `FileNotFoundException`. IMO using exceptions for functionality is poor design. `if` statements are nicer. `File#exists()` should be used, for example.

Comment: @4castle: But the `Scanner` will throw the exception.

Comment: I also prefer if statements. Thanks again for your tiime.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29

CreateNewFile will only throw:

```
IOException - If an I/O error occurred
SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method denies write access to the file
```

and will return:

```
true if the named file does not exist and was successfully created; false if the named file already exists
```

you should change your

```
catch (FileAlreadyExistsException e)
```

to

```
if(createFile)
```